# How to create custom configuration for JBoss 5.1.0?

Tags: configuration, jboss, jboss5.x

I need to create my own JBoss configuration.
It  will be a little changed "web" configuration.
Is there any documentation or tutorials - how to do it?

***What I need in new configuration:***
**1.** Remove JSF implementation included in the JBoss Application Server
*How to do it -* http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RemoveJSF

**2.** Add possibility to use twiddle in customized "web" configuration.
*How to do it -* modify jboss-service.xml.
Replace attribute

```
<attribute name="Port">-1</attribute>
```

with following attribute

```
<attribute name="Port">
   <value-factory bean="ServiceBindingManager" method="getIntBinding">
      <parameter>jboss:service=Naming</parameter>
      <parameter>Port</parameter>
   </value-factory>
</attribute>
```

for mbean

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingService"
      name="jboss:service=Naming"
      xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingService-xmbean.xml">
```

**3.** Remove **server/web/deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml**

**4.** ...in process...

PS.
***Does anyone know - why supoort of twiddle was disabled for web configuration?***

Comment: Good question... JBoss 5's modular system is completely different to JBoss 4, and a lot harder to get to grips with.

Comment: How do you wish to change the configuration? There are a great many things you can change, so it is helpful to understand what you are trying to change.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help - http://www.murraywilliams.com/computers/buildjboss/jboss3.html ?

Comment: This is for JBoss 3. But I need JBoss 5.

Comment: I don't think this is the right thing, but found this PDF, JBOSS isn't my bag, I'm a Tomcat guy - http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5custommetadatafiles.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To customize your own JBoss configuration that is based on the web configuration:

1. copy $JBOSS_HOME/server/web to $JBOSS_HOME/server/my_config
2. customize the configuration by editing the configuration files in my_config
3. start you new configuration by running

$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c my_config

or

%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/run.sh -c my_config

Comment: Yes, but the "customize the configuration" step is mightily complex, and that's what's being asked

Answer (score 0):

You can find information related to removing unused services in JBoss 5 in the [JBoss 5.x Tunning/Slimming guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5xTuningSlimming).

On the other hand, twiddle can be used with the web profile, what do you mean when you say it's not supported? But it cannot be used with the minimal configuration since the services twiddle relies on are disabled in this configuration.